# From Matlab to R: Capture named fields with regular expressions to a dataframe

Tags: regex, r, matlab

I want to capture name fields from a list of strings by using a regular expression. In `Matlab` I did it this way:

```
strings = {'sn555 ID_O20-5-684_N52_2_Subt2_01.',...
           'sn555 ID_O20-5-984_S52_8_Subt10_11.'};

pattern = ['sn(?<serial_number>.*) ID(_)(?<ID>.*)_(?<Class>[NS])'...
              '(?<Sector>.*)_(?<Point>(.*))_[Ss]ubt.*\.'];

ParsedData = regexp(strings,pattern,'names');
```

The result (converted to a **dataset**) is:

```
ParsedData = 
    serial_number    ID                 Class      Sector      Point  
    '555'            'O20-5-684'        'N'        '52'        '2'    
    '555'            'O20-5-984'        'S'        '52'        '8'
```

Now I want to parse these strings in `R` and convert the result to a dataframe.
I tried this:

```
strings <- c("sn555 ID_O20-5-684_N52_2_Subt2_01.",
             "sn555 ID_O20-5-984_S52_8_Subt10_11.")

pattern <- paste0('sn(?<serial_number>.*) ID(_)(?<ID>.*)_(?<Class>[NS])',
                  '(?<Sector>.*)_(?<Point>(.*))_[Ss]ubt.*\\.');

ParsedData <- gregexpr(pattern,strings, perl = TRUE);
ParsedData
```

Unfortunately, I'm new to regular expressions in R and the output (`ParsedData`) is confusing to me. What are your suggestions how to convert the `strings` to a dataset?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the past I wrote a helper function to extract capture groups from regular expressions called [regcapturedmatches.R](https://gist.github.com/MrFlick/10413321).

You can use it with your data like this:

```
rr <- regcapturedmatches(strings,ParsedData)
rr 
# [[1]]
#      serial_number X   ID          Class Sector Point X.1
# [1,] "555"         "_" "O20-5-684" "N"   "52"   "2"   "2"
# 
# [[2]]
#      serial_number X   ID          Class Sector Point X.1
# [1,] "555"         "_" "O20-5-984" "S"   "52"   "8"   "8"
```

You get a list back with an array with column names. You could turn that into a `data.frame` with:

```
do.call(rbind.data.frame, rr)

#   serial_number X        ID Class Sector Point X.1
# 1           555 _ O20-5-684     N     52     2   2
# 2           555 _ O20-5-984     S     52     8   8
```